# Property and Alias mapping don't seem to work

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper

I have a simple json like this

```
{
  "someReports":[
    {
      "reportName": "PR123",
      "fields": [
      ]
    },
    {
      "reportName": "PR234",
      "fields": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a class that looks somewhat like this inside which getSomeReports() is defined.

```
class AHeckLotOfReports {
  private String someString;
  private List<SomethingElse> some;
  ..
  @JsonProperty("someReports") 
  private List<SomeReports> someReports;
}
//POJO:
class SomeReport {
  String reportName;
  List<Field> fields;
...
}
//REST Controller looks like this. some injection code is cleaned up
@Api(tags = “SomeReport”)
@Controller
@ThreadSafe
@RequestMapping(“/report/v2")
        public class ReportController{
        @ApiOperation(value = "Create a new report.”)
                @RequestMapping(value = “/report”, method = RequestMethod.POST)
        @ResponseBody
        public ReportResponse addReport(
        @Nonnull final AuthorizationToken authorizationToken,
        @Nonnull@RequestBody final AHeckLotOfReports reportRequest) {
final Report report=this.reportService.addReport(
        authorizationToken,
        reportRequest.getName(),
        reportRequest.isEnabled(),
        reportRequest.getConfiguration().or(ReportConfiguration.empty()),
        reportRequest.getNewConfiguration(),
        reportRequest.getDefinition());
        return ReportResponse.fromReport(report);
        }
```

I haven't been able to get this working. I do get the structure intact but `reportName` comes up blank, the fields array comes up empty.
I have tried JsonAlias("someReports","some_reports") and that seems to make no difference.
Anything comes out as an obvious "duh" in this ?

EDIT: My apologies, I did realize I have not provided the entire context. I AM able to deserialize the simple POJO with ObjectMapper. But the class `AHeckLotOfReports` is used as request object in REST endpoint for a POST and this is where the problem surfaces

Software: jackson.core 2.9.9, jackson.datatype 2.9.8 and JDK 8.0, Spring-Boot 2.2.6

Comment: Did you try this `new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonAsString, AHeckLotOfReports.class);`? You can also add 

`@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` at the class level AHeckLotOfReports  to ignore the unknown fields

Comment: Can you provide the code of `SomeReports` pojo and your actual code how you serialize/deserialize the objects?

Comment: Could not reproduce your issue.  Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Voting to close so far.

Comment: @AlexRudenko Apologies for the details I omitted from the query. I have added a few details that I hope would provide more context

Comment: @Govind  Deserialization is done by the SpringBoot rest controller, not in my control. It might as well be a Spring issue and I apologize for lack of details in my earlier query

Comment: Did you add `(@RequestBody AHeckLotOfReports reports)` in your rest controller? Please share the code snippet of your Rest controller class as well.

Comment: @Govind I have added  gist of the REST controller

Comment: 1. Sample JSON is still invalid - it's missing at leat `{`.   2, `private someString` declaration does not compile.  3,  `someReports` field is not passed to `addReport` method in the controller method though it seems the request object is deserialized successfully,

Comment: @AlexRudenko, Sorry, some of the code is representative, the braces and String definition are corrected.  `addReport` is left out but in the debugger I can inspect the deserialized object and it comes with an empty collection. If things were in my control, I would deserialize with ObjectMapper successfully

Comment: See if you could use @RestController. Also, please try to add `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` to your request mapping. You can remove any manual jsonproperty annotations inside AHeckLotOfReports class.

Comment: Apologies, didn't mean to drop out. I tried ALL of the above, making the Controller RestController, removed manual JsonProperty annotations and we already have consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE. No difference so far.